# Writing to a file from a TextBox Lua

Tags: lua, textbox, coronasdk

Lately Ive been trying to make a basic word added. I want to make it so you tap on the text field and then you type what you need then it writes it to a .txt file (precreated or not) Im not great with coding and Im struggling to use the samples/other peoples Stack Exchange question to learn off. All I have is bits of code that dont work together and im not sure what I need to do to make them work **(the code isnt mine)**

```
local textBox = native.newTextBox( 200, 200, 280, 140 )
textBox.text = "This is line 1.\nAnd this is line2"
textBox.isEditable = true


local file = io.open( filePath, "r" )
if file then
-- read all contents of file into a string
local contents = file:read( "*a" )

print( "Contents of " .. filePath )
print( contents )

io.close( file ) -- Important to close (python knowledge)

local t = display.newText( "Contents of ", 5, 80, nil, 16 ); -- w, h, ?, size
t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 135/255 ); -- edit
local t = display.newText( filePath, 5, 100, nil, 10 );
t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 135/255 );

local ylast = 130 -- how far down the Y value it can make words on the screen
for line in io.lines(filePath) do
    local t = display.newText ( line, 15, ylast, nil, 14); -- dont understand
    t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 );
    ylast = ylast + 20
    end
end

local function inputListener( event )
if event.phase == "began" then

    -- user begins editing textBox
    print( event.text )

elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    textBox.text = event.text
    local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )

    local file = io.open( path, "w" )
    file:write( textBox.text )
    io.close( file )
    file = nil 

elseif event.phase == "editing" then

    print( event.newCharacters )
    print( event.oldText )
    print( event.startPosition )
    print( event.text )

end
end

textBox:addEventListener( "userInput", inputListener )
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the loadsave functions it makes it easier.

You can download these functions from here.

https://github.com/robmiracle/Simple-Table-Load-Save-Functions-for-Corona-SDK

Once downloaded just drop the loadsave.lua file into your main project folder.

Now you can use it like this.

Example:

```
local loadsave = require("loadsave")   

local tableToSave = {}

-- load text into a table
tableToSave ['saved-text'] = textYouWantToSave

-- save text
loadsave.saveTable(tableToSave, "filename.json")

local savedTable = {}

-- load text
savedTable = loadsave.loadTable("filename.json")

-- text is stored here
savedTable['saved-text']
```